# How to get project information from build in Scala project code?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Scala/sbt project. The project's version is in the sbt `Build.scala` file.

I need to have an "about" feature that gives the product version to the user.  How do I read from the SBT build file from within the Scala source?

For example, given **project/Build.scala**:

```
import sbt._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  val appName         = "foo-product"
  val appVersion      = "1.1.0"
}
```

What I'd really like is to just be able to do `ApplicationBuild.appVersion`, but that doesn't seem possible.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sbt-buildinfo`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) plugin.

The plugin generates a `BuildInfo` object, which contains information you need.