# How to export version from build.sbt to application.conf in Play?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

In `build.sbt` there's the setting:

```
version := "0.1.0"
```

How can I propagate its value to `application.conf` in Play:

```
app.ver = // the value of version from build.sbt
```

Please advise.

Comment: You may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/q/24088273/1305344 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23944108/1305344.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the value to be explicitly set in `application.conf` or just to be available at runtime? For this purpose I'm using the [SBT Buildinfo plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it the other way around?

In `application.conf`:

```
application.version="0.1.0"
```

In `build.sbt`:

```
import com.typesafe.config._

val confPath = Option(System.getProperty("config.file")).getOrElse("conf/application.conf")
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(confPath)).resolve()

version := conf.getString("application.version")
```

Another advantage to do it this way is that you have very easy access to the application version from within your application, e.g., for showing it in the footer of a page, etc.